# iOS: How to prevent video player from disappearing when going to background?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, streaming, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have an mpMoviePlayerViewController that streams a video from a remote server. It all works well, but I noticed that if I send the app to the background (by pressing the home button), when I reopen it, the mpMoviePlayerViewController stops playing and disappears.

Here is my code:

```
-(void)playVideo:(NSURL *)url{
    mpViewController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];

    if (mpViewController){
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
         addObserver: self
         selector: @selector(myMovieFinishedCallback:)
         name: MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
         object: mpViewController.moviePlayer];


        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
         addObserver: self
         selector: @selector(myMoviePreloadCallback:)
         name: MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification
         object: mpViewController.moviePlayer];
    }
}

-(void) myMoviePreloadCallback: (NSNotification*) aNotification{

    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(myMoviePreloadCallbackMainThread) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
}

-(void)myMoviePreloadCallbackMainThread{

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     removeObserver: self
     name: MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification
     object: mpViewController.moviePlayer];

    [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:mpViewController];

    [mpViewController.moviePlayer play];
}

-(void) myMovieFinishedCallback: (NSNotification*) aNotification
{

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     removeObserver: self
     name: MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
     object: mpViewController.moviePlayer];

    [mpViewController.moviePlayer stop];
    [self dismissMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated];
    [mpViewController release];
}
```

Is there a way to make the player continue playing from where it stopped?